# Is there a screencast recording application like screenr.com that allows more than 5 minutes?

Tags: webapp-rec

`Screenr.com` is a site that allows you to very easily create screencast videos, with no download/install (Java) and the ability to embed videos on your own site. However, it limits videos to 5 minutes in length.

Is there a similar web application service which allows a longer video length?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't comment yet, so I'll put it here.

Don't know about screencast web services, but if you are on linux you could use ffmpeg to grab the screen for all the time you want

```
ffmpeg -f alsa -ac 2 -i pulse -f x11grab -r 30 -s 1024x768 -i :0.0 -sameq output.mkv
```

Then upload to your favourite video hosting service

Comment: I've used ffmpeg on Windows as well, so this will probably work, thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try http://www.techsmith.com/jing/free/ there is no time limit to recording. There are also great features such as text box, arrow, highlight, or rectangle.

Answer (score 0):

Try [Screencast-O-Matic](http://www.screencast-o-matic.com/)

Free accounts get 15 minutes of recording.

Comment: Uses Java. from the OP: "with no download/install (Java)"